# C++ Writing Object to Binary File

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

Problem:

> Error: The "&" operator can only be applied to a variable or other l-value.

**What I've tried:**

- `dynamic_cast<char*>(e)`
- `reinterpret_cast<char*>(e)`
- `static_cast<char*>(e)`
- `(char*) e`

**What I'm trying to do:**

- Write the array e.data (private) to a binary file.

**Notes:**

- e.getSize() returns number of elements in array
- e[] returns Employee object.

Code:

```
fstream fout;
fout.open(filename.c_str(), ios::out|ios::binary);
if(fout.good())
{
    for(int i=0;i<e.getSize();i++)
    {
        fout.write((char*)&e[i], sizeof(e[i]));
    }
}
fout.close();
```

Employee.h

```
class Employee {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Employee &);
    private:
        int id;
        char name[50];
        char address[100];
        char phone[20];
        char department[100];
        int salary;
    public:
        Employee();
        ~Employee();
        Employee(int,char[],char[],char[],char[],int);
        bool operator==(Employee&);
};
```

I'm lost at what to do, from what I remember `fout.write((char*)&e[i], sizeof(e[i]));` is how to write to binary files.

**Edit:**
e is declared like so:
   `MYLIB::Bucket<Employee> e;`

```
template <class T>
class Bucket {
    private:
        T* bkt;
        int size;
        int capacity;
        static const int stepsize = 10;

    public:
        Bucket();
        ~Bucket();

        void push_back(const T&);
        T operator[](int);
        int getSize();
        int getCapacity();
};
```

**Edit 2:**
`fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(e[i]), sizeof(e[i]));` gives me line 122: Error: Using reinterpret_cast to convert from ? to char* not allowed. (Line 122 is the line just quoted)

**Edit 3:**

```
tempemp = e[i];
fout.write((char*)(&tempemp), sizeof(e[i]));
```

<strike>Compiles but gives a segmentation fault, I'll investigate why.</strike>
Compiles, the segmentation fault looks unrelated.

Comment: what is the declaration of `e`?

Comment: Somewhat related: I would advise against writing a binary file based on a platform-specific packing of a structure like that.

Comment: Added declaration of e. The choice of binary file is not my own, it's part of an exercise.

Comment: Isn't T operator[](int); returning a temporary object that has to be assigned to something before it has an address?
T& operator[](int); might be better

Comment: Would Edit 3 fix that?

Comment: I don't suppose those Bucket objects are *ever* copied around (even implicitly in ways you may not think about, such as a by-val parameter to a function, etc.) ?? If so, you have a basic nightmare ala-RuleOfThree violation in your code.

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't know what by-val or RuleOfThree is?

Comment: Now you have two basic nightmares. :)

Comment: @JohnSmith I've a reasonable suspicion you're about to find out the hard way. Hit up Wiki with [`"C++ Rule of Three"`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C++_programming)).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)
I think the point is that if you need the == operator you should also have a copy constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that

```
T operator[](int);
```

is returning a temporary object that must be bound to something before an address can be taken

```
const Employee& emp = e[i];
fout.write((char*)&emp, sizeof(emp));
```

might work, assuming [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2616180/259) is correct that taking a reference extends the life of a temporary object

An alternative might be to return a reference to the object, which would remove the creation of temporary objects

```
const T& operator[](int);
```

Comment: Error: Initializing Employee& requires an lvalue.

Comment: I'll give the second idea a go.

Answer (score 4):

```
 MYLIB::Bucket<Employee> e;
```

this seems to be a container. `e[i]` gives you an `Employee` by value. you need to get this object's address using `&e[i]` but you can'd do that since it's an r-value so you need to copy it to a non r-value:

```
Employee copye = e[i];
fout.write((char*)&copye, sizeof(e[i]));
```

Should work.

On a side note, this all looks like terrible code and I don't envy whoever needs to maintain or read it. A few points:

- you should not be using the binary format of the in-memory object as your serialization format. Use a proper serialization format like protobuf or xml or json
- Why pull your own strange containers when you can use `std::vector` `std::list` ? re-inventing the wheel is always bad
- returning an element by value from a container creates copies which degrade performance.